# Java Refresh the access token to access google api

Tags: java, api, access-token

When I try to run the command refresh the access token and get access token value is refreshed I get the following error.Please tell me how to fix it

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)

at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:320)

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:515)

at demo.NewClass2.main(NewClass2.java:38)
```

Mycode : I think because I set missing for GoogleCredential,so I can't refresh token

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String refreshToken = "";
            String clientID = "";
            String clienSecret = "";
            String p12 = "";

            HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setClientSecrets(clientID, clienSecret)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(p12))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(BloggerScopes.BLOGGER))
                    .build();
            credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
            credential.refreshToken();
            System.out.println(credential.getAccessToken());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Well I've posted the full stacktrace,